# Passing multiple proxies to send data to influx by telegraf

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I have to monitor my on-premise mongodb using telegraf. My influxdb which is acting as a metric collector is installed in a private subnet on cloud. For my telegraf to send data to my influxdb, it has to pass through proxy.

One proxy will allow it to send data to internet ( On-premise) 
The other one will be pass the data through bastion server which is in public subnet to my influxdb.

How can do this.
My telegraf agent is installed on a windows machine and my influx is on a ubuntu server. My bastion is also a ubuntu server

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the data to two different influxdb instances (or [outputs](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/outputs/influxdb))?

If yes you just need to use two separate "outputs" in the same config

ie output to two different influxdb instances:

```
#Telegraf Config File
{... Agent, inputs, etc ...}

#output to first db
[[outputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["__InfluxEndpoint__"]
  http_proxy = "__ProxyUrl__"
  {...}

#output to second db
[[outputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["__InfluxEndpoint__"]
  http_proxy = "__ProxyUrl__"
  {...}
```

Sorry if I ask for more details in the reply but I don't have enough reputation to add comments

Comment: No that is not the use case.I think you misunderstood. My influxdb is in private subnet in cloud and telegraf behind internet proxy on premise. Now how can telegraf send data to influx?

Comment: Sorry but I can't help with this, but maybe you can this ask in the [influx community](https://community.influxdata.com/) (if you didn't already)